# Popover tableview Controller not showing Data Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, popover

My Popover Controller is popping up with a blank TableView and I have no idea why. I have tried changing the color of the cell and view and this doesn't even seem to show up when I click the popover.

Here is the code for initiating the popover:

```
@IBAction func popOverButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{

    let controller = TableViewController()
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    // configure the Popover presentation controller
    let popController: UIPopoverPresentationController? = controller.popoverPresentationController
    popController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.down]
    popController?.delegate = self
    popController?.sourceView = sender
    popController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    popController?.backgroundColor = .white
    self.parent?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { })

}

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
{
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

[This Code Shows This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyF2I.png)

Here is my code for my Tableview controller, I had tried the other method before of making a regular ViewController putting a tableview on to  it but that yielded the same results.
    import UIKit

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var categories = PTTableView().titles
//PTTableview.titles is a populated array from another viewcontroller     and it is not empty
@IBOutlet var tableiViewOne: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
            return categories.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell = tableiViewOne.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! PopOverTableViewCell

    cell.cellLabelOne.text = categories[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

}
```

And yes the tableviewcontroller on the storyboard is set to the TableViewController.

UPDATE:
I Have Changed the number of sections on the tableviewcontroller to 1 and now my app is crashing saying fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 
Highlighting

```
let cell = tableiViewOne.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! PopOverTableViewCell
```

I have the same cell name on the storyboard and It is set to the same class

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `0` for the `numberOfSections` method. That will generate an empty table.

You should at least have 1 section to display your data. So you need to change it to `return 1`

Comment: I did that and now it says  unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value highlighting my let cell =

Comment: Did you set your tableViewCell in your story board to `PopOverTableViewCell`?

Comment: assign "myCell" in reuseIdentifier in storyboard cell

Comment: @SamR. Check the IBOutlet connection of your `tableiViewOne` to your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the dataSource and delegate?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```